# Conditional dropdowns with react-final-form and react-select using parse and format

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-final-form

This is a follow-up question to [several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58422329/5117125) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58774130/5117125) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55024727/5117125), but the solution found (`<PickOptions />` [component by Erik Rasmussen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-field-arrays-so-4d1mu?file=/index.js)) doesn't seem to work for select options manipulated by [parse](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps#parse) and [format](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps#format).

I want to "flatten" the options objects into just their value when storing in the form state (and change them back into option objects for rendering with `react-select`), so I did the following:

```
const SelectAdapter = ({ input, ...rest }) => (
  <Select {...input} {...rest} searchable />
);

const options = [
  { value: "two-a", label: "Two A" },
  { value: "two-b", label: "Two B" }
];
```

```
<Field
  name={fieldName}
  component={SelectAdapter}
  options={options}
  parse={(formattedOption) => formattedOption ? formattedOption.value : undefined}
  format={(parsedValue) => options.find((option) => option.value === parsedValue)}
/>
```

And changed one line in `PickOptions` like so:

```
-const aValue = aField.input.value.value;
+const aValue = aField.input.value;
```

Now `PickOptions` seems to properly clear the value of the child/dependent select field as far as react-final-form state/values are concerned, but it still renders the old value in the select field and I cannot figure out why. Any help would be most appreciated! Thanks in advance.

[CodeSandbox demonstrating the problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-conditional-flattened-dropdowns-so-uscd0): choose an option in the first dropdown, then choose an option in the second dropdown. Next, change the first dropdown to the other option. It should clear the second dropdown (you'll notice it clears the actual value in the form, in the values printed below the inputs, but leaves the old label text of the previously selected option in the second/child dropdown). You may also notice the Reset button empties the form values internally but does not clear the inputs. Same root cause, I'm assuming.

**(edit) Super Hacky Workaround?**

```
const SelectAdapter = ({ input, ...rest }) => {
  const [hack, setHack] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (rest.options) setHack((hack) => hack + 1);
  }, [rest.options]);

  return <Select key={hack} {...input} {...rest} searchable />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure. If you `console.log()` the `options` when rendering `childOption`, they *do* change. So maybe `react-select` is ignoring changes to the `options` prop? Doesn't seem to be a problem with RFF, from what I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for looking, Erik! I agree, all troubleshooting I performed seems to indicate it should be fine (especially RFF). I came up with a total hack in the React Select adapter, but I'm not sure if it has any negative implications. I applied a `key` prop to `Select` and increment it in an effect whenever `options` changes. ‍♂️

Comment: That's a hack, but it'll work, forcing a remounting of the select component every time. Probably good enough. 

Comment: Hi everyone i see your post and i have a similar problem in my form, but i can not adapt to my code. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/clear-drop-down-menu-options-97udog?file=/src/App.js

Could you help me? 
this is my post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560651/clear-second-drop-menu-when-change-the-first-drop-down-menu-react-final-form